# External Flash Loader linker script file

Tags: stm32, linker-scripts

I'm trying to make a custom external flash loader for my STM32F746 uC based board and i found some templates for this purpose from  [this link](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32-external-loader/tree/contrib) that is belongs to the ST workshop on [this YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfsKsZDGdb8). So when i dug into the corresponding files i saw that in a linker script file named `linker.ld` the RAM memory region is defined from base address 0x20000004 though i know that the RAM memory region in STM uCs starts from address 0x20000000:

```
MEMORY
{
   RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000004, LENGTH = 320K
}
```

I searched for many other templates file existing in [this link](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32-external-loader) and also they are using the same way for RAM memory region base address.

So the problem is why we must define RAM memory address from 0x20000004 for external flash loader algorithm to store in and not from 0x20000000 instead. Could anyone please help me to explain the reason and tell me that what will happen if we do the:

```
MEMORY
{
   RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 320K
}
```

instead of previous one and what errors might be occurred?

Thanks.

Comment: It is probably typo or first 4 bytes are reserved silly way.

Comment: thanks for reply. im really confused about